# FullCalendar not updating events on date change

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

This is probably incredibly simple, and I've probably *almost* had the solution, but I've got a horrid cold and my brain is misfiring.

Problem: In a month-view, when I click for the next/previous month, the events for that month are not loading; as an example, when the calendar populates, it shows the events for November. If I click next to view December, the events for December do not render. I'm using Google calendars as the event sources. Code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#teenCal").fullCalendar({
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCnfBoDwvGDCIfltN7P_ys-5MW5GGIYq8Q',
        events: { googleCalendarId: 'gchrl.org_2jguin31a4ac76bpbri5dq6jb4@group.calendar.google.com',
               backgroundColor: 'purple',
               borderColor: 'purple' },
        header: { left: 'prev',
                  center: 'title',
                  right: 'next' },
     });    
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link media="print" href="http://examplesite.com/resources/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://examplesite.com/resources/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://examplesite.com/resources/fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://examplesite.com/resources/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://examplesite.com/resources/fullcalendar/gcal.js" ></script>
<script src="http://examplesite.com/resources/js/custom.js"></script> <!-- Contains script above -->
</head>
<body>
   <div id="teenCal"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried lazyFetching = false, refetching events on renderView(), nothing seems to work.

EDIT: Changed the calendar to one that has events in November and December. Here's my use of refetching on renderView() - I have no idea if it's correctly done or not.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#teenCal").fullCalendar({
        aspectRatio: 1.5,
        googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyCnfBoDwvGDCIfltN7P_ys-5MW5GGIYq8Q',
        events: { googleCalendarId: 'gchrl.org_2jguin31a4ac76bpbri5dq6jb4@group.calendar.google.com',
        backgroundColor: 'purple',
        borderColor: 'purple' },
        header: { left: 'prev', center: 'title', right: 'next' },
        viewRender: function(view, element) {
            element.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
            }
    });
});
```

Now, to my mind, based on the documentation that should work. But I'm probably misunderstanding what the "element" is in the viewRender call, or not implementing it correctly.

Comment: There is a recent change in Google Calendar's API, so you will need to update a file from the resources. You can find more information on this link: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/

Comment: I'm already using the latest revision of FullCalendar and the appropriate code for the changes to the Google API.